# “Ingénieur du logiciel” or “ingénieur en logiciel”?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions, professions

When speaking in French I have always told people *je suis un ingénieur du logiciel,* (a software engineer) and nobody has corrected me. Yesterday, however, someone online told me it was better to say *ingénieur **en** logiciel.*

I found google results for both... are both correct? Is there a difference? Does it apply to all types of engineer?

Comment: French speakers would use the expression "ingénieur (en) informatique".

Comment: Or "ingénieur informaticien" - but this was ridiculized years ago by a funny french song  :-). Actually nobody says "ingénieur en logiciel".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By saying "*ingénieur du logiciel*", you are saying that you are the engineer of this software (which software depending on context). While correct, this is not what you meant to say.

"*ingénieur en logiciel*" means "engineer in software (science)", which is what you meant.

You can also omit the "*en*", and simply say "*ingénieur logiciel*" (I personally prefer this way, but both are correct).

As a general rule, we do not use "*ingénieur de [specialité]*" but "*ingénieur en [specialité]*".

Comment: +1 - par simplicité, c'est généralisé à ingénieur système, ingénieur unix, ingénieur (technologie XX). software science = génie logiciel en français. ingénieur en génie logiciel est un pléonasme. et de manière générale, l'ingénierie (pratique) s'oppose à la science (académique), assembler les 2 notions n'est pas claire.

Answer (score 4):

Although being in the CS industry since more than three decades, I never heard the expression *Ingénieur du logiciel* and seldom *Ingénieur en logiciel*

The most common terms used to translate software engineer are ***[Ingénieur en développement logiciel](http://www.lesjeudis.com/article/cb-260-ingenieur-developpement-logiciels)*** and ***[Ingénieur Études et Développement (en informatique)](http://www.cadresonline.com/conseils/coaching/fiches-metiers-salaires/fiches-metiers/detail/article/ingenieur-etudes-et-developpement.html)***. Unlike *Développeur* which has a wider acception, they both match the definition found in [webopedia](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/software_engineer.html) that clearly states it is illegal to hold the engineer title without the required license.

---

Bien qu'étant dans l'informatique depuis plus de trente ans, je n'ai jamais rencontré l'expression « Ingénieur du logiciel », très peu « Ingénieur en logiciel ».

Pour traduire *Software engineer*, les termes les plus courants sont **[Ingénieur en développement logiciel](http://www.lesjeudis.com/article/cb-260-ingenieur-developpement-logiciels)** et **[Ingénieur Études et Développement (en Informatique)](http://www.cadresonline.com/conseils/coaching/fiches-metiers-salaires/fiches-metiers/detail/article/ingenieur-etudes-et-developpement.html)**. Contrairement à développeur qui s'applique à un spectre plus large de profils, ils correspondent à la définition que l'on peut par exemple trouver sur [webopedia](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/software_engineer.html) qui indique clairement qu'il est illégal aux États-Unis d'utiliser ce titre pour un non diplômé.

Comment: Uh..."they both match the definition found in webopedia that clearly states it is illegal to hold the engineer title without the required license.".....at least in the US this is not something that people think about when saying what they do in this field so I'm a bit confused. It's just...."I'm a software engineer" or "I'm a software developer", etc.

Comment: @Aerovistae Granted but in France and when applying to a technical (non sales) position, it is unlikely for someone not holding this title to state (s)he is *Ingénieur* .

Answer (score 1):

Une réponse spécifique au Québec :

> **Développeur** ((de) logiciel, etc.)
>
> Personne responsable de la définition d'un problème qui sera résolu
> grâce à l'informatique, de la conception des procédures qui seront
> utilisées pour traiter ce problème et de l'écriture du programme
> nécessaire, qui peut également prendre en charge la maintenance et
> l'évolution du programme.
>
> [ Grand dictionnaire terminologique (GDT) - [développeur](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8369621) ]

Un développeur est un développeur. Mais on veut parfois parler du rôle de *spécialiste*, du développeur *spécialisé en/dans* ou du rôle de concepteur etc. Et donc ce peut être le rôle de l'[*ingénieur (en) logiciel*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26500449) ([2](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=INGENIEUR%20LOGICIEL&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)) qui *travaille à la conception, au développement, à la mise en œuvre et à l'exploitation des systèmes logiciels d'une entreprise ou d'une organisation* (GDT).<sup>1</sup> Enfin il s'agit bien généralement du domaine de l'[*informatique*](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2071561), discipline englobant autant les aspects théoriques et pratiques. Certains on parlé de *software science/science logicielle* : c'est peu usité à mon avis en Amérique du nord (et absent au *Termium/GDT*). Ça [semble](https://books.google.com/books?id=E5GtZXMNoewC&pg=PR25&dq=%22software%20science%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3hdqX2tTKAhXDkx4KHTZXBGUQ6AEIXDAI#v=onepage&q=%22software%20science%22&f=false) être une spécialité, un truc comme l'*analyse quantitative de l’algorithmique*, et ne réfère ni à l'informatique généralement ni à la programmation comme telle (au Québec).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Ce rôle n'en fait pas pour autant à lui seul un « *ingénieur* » au Québec, et s'y représenter, en utilisant le titre d'*ingénieur*, avec ou sans qualificatif, abrévié ou non, sur une carte d'affaire par exemple, constitue un délit passible d'un amende variant de 1500$ à 20 000$ pour une personne physique, et entre 3000$ et 40 000$ pour une personne morale, lors d'une première [infraction](http://www2.publicationsduquebec.gouv.qc.ca/dynamicSearch/telecharge.php?type=2&file=/C_26/C26.htm) ([Eng.](http://www2.publicationsduquebec.gouv.qc.ca/dynamicSearch/telecharge.php?type=2&file=/C_26/C26_A.html)) (art. 32, 188). Il s'agit d'un titre professionnel [réservé](http://www2.publicationsduquebec.gouv.qc.ca/dynamicSearch/telecharge.php?type=2&file=/I_9/I9.html) ([Eng.](http://www2.publicationsduquebec.gouv.qc.ca/dynamicSearch/telecharge.php?type=2&file=/I_9/I9_A.html)) (art. 1-3, 5, 22, 26), avec actes réservés dans différents champs de pratique ; un *ingénieur* est un membre [en règle](http://www2.publicationsduquebec.gouv.qc.ca/dynamicSearch/telecharge.php?type=3&file=/I_9/I9R4_A.HTM) ([2](http://www2.publicationsduquebec.gouv.qc.ca/dynamicSearch/telecharge.php?type=2&file=//C_26/C26R2.htm)) de l'*Ordre des ingénieurs du Québec*. Les champs de pratique varient et les ingénieurs ont des spécialités (liées à des [choix](http://www.polymtl.ca/etudes/bc/) de formation) mais ils sont tous également *ingénieurs* au Québec. Enfin une société exerçant une activité au Québec ne peut généralement avoir un nom contenant les mots *ingénieur, ingénierie, génie* ou *engineer, engineering*, à moins que ce soit depuis avant 1964 (art. 26). Voir enfin généralement au dictionnaire *ingénieur* ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ing%C3%A9nieur), [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ing%C3%A9nieur/43051/locution?q=ing%C3%A9nieur#180106)).</sub>

Comment: Développeur est un terme largement utilisé aussi de ce côté-ci de l'Atlantique et ici également, tous les développeurs n'ont pas le titre d'ingénieur.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci. En effet _développeur_ a un spectre plus large comme on dit. Intéressant mais ça dépasse le cadre de la Q. ;[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_and_licensure_in_engineering), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_engineer). La réglementation va varier par état aux É.-U., selon qu'on traite d'_engineer_ tout court ou _software engineer_ etc. Mon avis c'est qu'on fait fausse route en émulant ça. Il n'y a qu'une seule _ingénierie_, appliquée à un multitude de domaines dont l'informatique. C'est une formation en sciences. Pour moi n'existe que l'ingénieur licencié.