# What are Software Engineers called in France?

Tags: informatique

I grew up in Geneva Switzerland and on a visit there last year I was asked what I do and completely drew a blank. I eventually said "programmeur" but that just means "programmer" which could be anything. But as a Software Engineer I build software front to back using a variety of technologies. I googled it but apparently "Ingenieur de logiciel" is not really a thing? I'm so confused there's no straightforward "this is what software engineers are called in france".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Programmeur* is not that much used nowadays.

I would suggest one of:

> *Développeur* (widely used term)
>
> *Ingénieur en développement logiciel* (a bit formal)
>
> *Ingénieur en génie logiciel* (to be used in a CV more than a conversation)

[Pôle Emploi](http://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/marche-du-travail/fichemetierrome?codeRome=M1805) is reporting more than 80 different names for this occupation and its variants (toggle the *Appellations métier* <kbd>+</kbd> icon).

See also [“Ingénieur du logiciel” or “ingénieur en logiciel”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17572/ing%C3%A9nieur-du-logiciel-or-ing%C3%A9nieur-en-logiciel/17616#17616)

Comment: I usually use the term `développeur logiciel` but I guess the rest of your answers are also used

Comment: @guillau4 Yes, developpeur logiciel is also used and even [official](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9veloppeur_logiciel)

Answer (score 1):

Here in Quebec we use

> ingénieur logiciel

I cannot speak for other francophone countries, but a quick search on different french job search websites gave me a fair amount of *Ingénieur logiciel*. Actual people from France could confirm.

It is in the same vein as

> Computer engineer > *ingénieur informatique*

or

> IT engineer > *ingénieur TI*

Same thing with non-IT fields:

> civil engineer > *ingénieur civil*

or

> mechanical engineer > *ingénieur mécanique*.

Comment: Thanks, but I read somewhere that `ingenieur` implies that you actually have a formal degree in engineering.

Comment: In many places, engineer is a protected title while engineering is a protected act for those who are registered as engineers.

Since you called yourself an engineer, I thought this was the case.

Comment: No I call myself a Software Engineer because that's my work title, and yeah we do "engineer" solutions to business problems. But I'm not an Engineer in the formal sense.