# Quelle est la différence entre "écoles d'ingénieurs" et "écoles d'ingénierie" ?

Tags: académique, université, supérieur

Je viens de rencontrer le terme "école d'ingénierie".
(voir https://www.dimension-ingenieur.com/)

Je me demande quelle(s) est(sont) la(les) différence(s) entre une école d'ingénieur et une école d'ingénierie (s'il y en a bien sûr) ?

Comment: @stbr  Je crois qu'il y a des différences. Je pense que une école d'ingénieur (consulaire, privée, publique) est réconnue par Cti par contre une école d'ingénierie ne l'est pas. Mais il me faut vérifier si j'ai raison ou pas:-)! Je vous remercie pour votre commentaire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comme Alex et WIP l'ont dit, c'est la CTI (Commission des Titres d'Ingénieur) qui attribue à une école la qualité d'école d'ingénieurs (elle évalue le programme de cours, les associations, la mobilité internationale, ...).

Cette habilitation n'est pas donnée à vie et doit être renouvelée (une école d'ingénieurs peut donc perdre ce titre).

Il en ressort plusieurs subtilités :

- un élève diplômé d'une école d'ingénieurs aura un titre d'ingénieur diplômé. Le mot titre est important. Comme l'accès à ce titre est réglementé, il a une *valeur*. Il ne peut pas non plus être usurpé.
- une école d'ingénierie n'a aucune habilitation donnée par l'état. Et donc aucun titre. Il en ressort que la formation d'une école d'ingénierie n'est pas garantie.

Pour être moi-même élève en école d'ingénieurs, j'ai souvent eu à répondre à ce genre de question en salon étudiant, ou à informer des élèves. Le nom école d'ingénierie est piégeux car si l'on ne connait pas la différence, on peut penser que la formation est la même.
Or, si la différence entre une école d'ingénieurs et une école d'ingénierie peut être minime (une mobilité internationale insuffisante par exemple), elle peut aussi être très grande. Des élèves peuvent donc ainsi s'engager dans des écoles payantes (souvent chères) sans garantit d'avoir un diplôme *reconnu*.

Mais on s'éloigne du français.
Ici, il faut reconnaître que l'école *d'ingénieurs* fait implicitement référence à *ingénieurs diplômés*.

> Un étudiant d’une école habilitée par l’État à délivrer un diplôme d'ingénieur, devient après ses études « ingénieur diplômé (de l'école concernée, avec éventuellement mention d'une spécialité) ». Seuls ceux-ci ont ce titre. Depuis 1934, une personne usurpant le titre d'« ingénieur diplômé » (le mot diplômé est ici important car il montre le rattachement du diplôme à la CTI) est passible d’un emprisonnement d’un an et d’une amende de 15 000€.

*Disclaimer : je ne souhaite pas rabaisser les écoles d'ingénierie ni faire preuve d'élitisme. Certaines possèdent un programme éducatif très solide, parfois plus que les écoles d'ingénieurs. Cependant si elles n'ont pas reçus une habilitation, il y a souvent une raison.*

[Ingénieur en France wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ing%C3%A9nieur#En_France)

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse. Je viens de corriger une faute de frappe (je crois) : habilitation (vous avez écris abilitation).

Comment: de plus une ecole reconnue par la cti a un volume obligatoire de certaines matieres (math, physique, automatique, etc..) ce qui donne au diplomé un ensemble de connaissances transverses.

Comment: @OznOg une école d'ingénierie peut très bien avoir le même volume. Comme je l'ai dit, il n'est pas *garantit*. Mais un élève en école d'ingénierie peut avoir le même (ou un meilleur) ensemble de connaissances transverses qu'un élève ingénieur

Answer (score 4):

"École d'ingénieurs" est un statut particulier attribué par l'état à travers la [CTI](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commission_des_titres_d%27ing%C3%A9nieur) donnant le droit de délivrer un diplôme d'ingénieur (diplôme d'états équivalent d'un Master 2).

Je n'ai jamais entendu parler d'école d'ingénierie mais ça pourrait être un terme pour désigner une école dont les objectifs sont similaires mais qui n'a pas l'habilitation de l'état.
[Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projet:Enseignement_sup%C3%A9rieur_en_France/R%C3%A8gle_de_nommage_des_articles#Cas_des_%C3%A9coles_accr%C3%A9dit%C3%A9es_pour_d%C3%A9livrer_un_dipl%C3%B4me_d'ing%C3%A9nieur)

Answer (score 4):

Les écoles d'ingénierie ne sont pas habilitées par la Commission des Titres d’Ingénieur.

Sources : http://www.apres-le-bac.fr/ecole-ingenieur/ecoles-ingenieur-ecole-ingenierie-quelles-differences/
https://www.orientation-education.com/article/formations-ingenieurs-ecole-universite

Answer (score 3):

Évidemment, la différence est l'emploi du domaine (l'*ingénierie*, voire le *génie*) ou du titre associée à la profession (*ingénieur*(e)). Le site qu'on a consulté est adapté à la France. Au Québec, on peut noter que l'École Polytechnique affiliée à l'Université de Montréal se définit comme une [*université d'ingénierie*](https://www.polymtl.ca/renseignements-generaux/) mais réfère dans son [historique](https://www.polymtl.ca/renseignements-generaux/historique) au fait qu'« il s’agissait de la première école francophone d'ingénieurs en Amérique ». À l'université [McGill](https://www.mcgill.ca/engineering/) on a en anglais la « Faculty of Engineering ». Toutes les [formations](https://www.polymtl.ca/futur/survol) à Polytechnique traitent de *génie*.

**Au Québec, le terme employé pour désigner ou qualifier l'institution qui dispense ces formations n'est absolument pas pertinent**, ces formations mènent essentiellement toutes à l'obtention du grade de baccalauréat en ingénierie (B.Ing./Eng.). Indépendamment, la [loi](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ShowDoc/cr/C-26,%20r.%202) (*Règlement sur les diplômes délivrés par les établissements d’enseignement désignés qui donnent droit aux permis et aux certificats de spécialistes des ordres professionnels* : voir 1.21) liste nommément les diplômes des institutions donnant ouverture au permis délivré par l’Ordre des ingénieurs du Québec, dont ceux mentionnés (d'autres [cheminements](https://www.oiq.qc.ca/fr/jeSuis/candidat/obtenirUnPermis/cheminement/Pages/description.aspx) sont possibles, dont l'équivalence/les ententes internationales). Au Québec, le titre réservé est celui d'*ingénieur* (et non pas d'*ingénieur diplômé*, comme en France) ; seul un membre de l'Ordre des ingénieurs du Québec est un *ingénieur* au Québec, indépendamment du nom de sa formation, d'où elle s'est déroulée ou du nom de l'institution qui la dispense, et le terme, seul ou avec tout autre qualificatif, même en abréviation, est réservé (voir [art. 22](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ShowDoc/cs/I-9/)) ainsi que les actes qui lui sont associés (voir art. 2 et 3 ; voir aussi [ceci](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17616)).

L'importance qu'on attache ou non au mot qualifiant l'*école* en question est simplement tributaire d'un aménagement législatif différent.